# How To get TextField Values form one JFrame to a class by action of JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to save the text field data of my frame to a local variable in a class of the same package after I click a button. I don't know how to do it.

Class name :- data.
Frame name :- smtp_settings.

[I want to store UserId and Password in a String variable in a class data by action of the button Save. This is the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2V8i.png)

What should be the coding for the data to be stored?

Please help me.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Add an listener action for you button(SAVE).

More info from [Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

```
SAVE.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         //After click SAVE-button, userID and password are your text fields

         //getting text
         String user_id = userID.getText();
         String psw = password.getText();
         // ... 
     }
});
```

More details will be helpful.

Comment: The variables are in another class namely "data".